# Google Charts right-to-left

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using Google Charts to display charts on our website.
We want the charts to read properly from right-to-left.
I can find the `<svg>` elements and add `style="direction: rtl;"` to them. That will fix the text alignment, but it throws everything else off.
I want the axis labels to be on the right (or at least correctly aligned with the axis on the left).
I want the text to be aligned right-to-left.
Setting `{'langugae': 'he'}` in the `load` function has no `rtl` effect. All it does is change the langugae of the `aria` attributes.

Properly aligned (ltr) axis
[image: Properly aligned (ltr) axis]

After setting the `style` attribute of the `svg`.
[image: After setting the style attribute of the svg.]

EDIT (code):

```
google.charts.load('current', {'language': 'he'});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(() => {
  this.drawVisualization();
});

drawVisualization() {
  ...
  this.wrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper(settings);
  this.chartData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(this.tableData);
  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(this.wrapper, 'ready', () => this.chartReady());
}

chartReady(){
  ...
  let svgs = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
  if (svgs && svgs.length > 0){
    Array.from(svgs).forEach(element => {
      element.setAttribute('style', 'direction: rtl');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add your code

Answer (score 1):

there's a built-in property for this,

`dataTable.rtlTable(true)`

you can find more about it in their docs -

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table

בהצלחה!

Comment: That property only exists on the Table chart. Not any other chart, say SteppedArea chart.